# How to apply constraints and use NO Action rules mean Take NO ACTION

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm trying to clarify the correct use of foreign-key contraints and keep hitting a blank when it comes to 'ON DELETE' 'NO ACTION'
I'll keep things generic since iis very simple without drilling into the finite detail.

> I have a Parent table which has 5 child tables - there is exisiting
>   data in all of the tables (its not a new DB build). I want to set
>   things up logically to fit what my client needs and i would expect!
>   There is a one-many relationship with all parent to child tables
>   hence: There can be zero or many records relatinbg to a parent table
>   primary-key rec. There can never be a child record that does not
>   relate to a parent records (ive already checked to ensure this is so).

Since there maybe (and probably  are) parent records without and child records in any child table right now then setting up Parent-to-Child restraints is failing, OK i understand why, no problem.
So ill set up Child-to-Parent restraints thus:

- If a child record (Fk) is UPDATED, Update the Parent (PK) to the same.
- If a child record (Fk) is DELETED, allow the deletion of the child, but take no action on the Parent (Pk) record (Super Important!)
- If a parent record is deleted then delete it and all related child records in ALL child tables

However im reading threads on SO and MySQL docs which say 'NO ACTION' is the same as 'RESTRICT' which is going to cause problems if i cant delete child records.
I'm using mainly 'INSERT INTO' statements in my PHP code with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' statements. 
My inclination is to remove the foreign-key constraints altogether from the DB level and just enforce what i want to achieve as im doing in my PHP/PDO.
I'm actually using foreign-key constraints because i think i have to but not really getting the point since Updating a primary-key should never happen anyway.

What is the best way to do this. What is a good use case for 'NO ACTION' if it actually prevents rather than protects.

Comment: Sometimes `FOREIGN KEYs` are more hassle than they are worth.  Do keep in mind that FKs have only a very limited functionality.  If you need anything fancier, it is better to do it in application code or triggers or stored routines.

Comment: @Rick, my thoughts exactly - i don't think an inability to create foreign-key rules is an indication of poor database design; sometimes they just dont fit and you should re-in-force your own.

Answer (score 0):

> 'NO ACTION' is the same as 'RESTRICT' which is going to cause problems if i cant delete child records.

That's not what that condition means. It doesn't prevent you from deleting *child* records, it prevents you from deleting *parent* records if and only if child records exist that depend on the parent record.

Example:

A table `Orders` has a one-to-many relationship with `LineItems`, and a foreign key in `LineItems` has the restrict option.

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
  order_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (order_id)
);

CREATE TABLE LineItems (
  lineitem_id INT NOT NULL,
  order_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (lineitem_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES Orders (order_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

Create some test data:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO Orders SET order_id = 123;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO LineItems SET lineitem_id = 1, order_id = 123;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
```

We can't delete the Orders record because there's a LineItem depending on it:

```
mysql> DELETE FROM Orders WHERE order_id = 123;
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`lineitems`, CONSTRAINT `lineitems_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `Orders` (`order_id`))
```

But we can delete a LineItems record anytime we want:

```
mysql> DELETE FROM LineItems WHERE order_id = 123;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

Now that there are no LineItems records referencing the Orders record, we can delete that one too:

```
mysql> DELETE FROM Orders WHERE order_id = 123;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Bill Karwin and contributors to this question. I have since realised the DB setup was incorrect which is why i needed to remove the FK constraints in order to work with it. The DB was migrated from MS Access and, as well as some data-type differences, the foreign-key constraint checks were switched off when importing the DB into mySQL without doing this importing was impossible. This alone was an indication of problems with the constraints rules setup in MS Access.

Working with the exported db now in MySQL revealed many orphan records and indexed fields which already violated the FK constraints by being null or empty! - on fixing these and normalising the DB/Tables properly the suggestions here were founded.

Thanks for your input.